# angular 6 ngx-treeview custom styling

Tags: html, angular6, ellipsis, treeviewitem, ngx-treeview

I am using **ngx-treeview** component in my angular 6 project. My **tree-view** items are very lengthy. So, I'm trying to apply `text-overflow:ellipsis` in the `./treeview-container` `.row-item`. snippet goes like this

```
  :host /deep/ .treeview-container .row-item {
    margin-bottom: .3rem;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width:100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

width is set to `100px` and my text is truncated but the ellipsis is not applied. Could you support me in applying custom css?
Also I need to display full text on **hovering**. Does **":hover"** works on **treeview-item**?

PS: I tried the same for `./treeview-item` also but didn't work.

Comment: were able to fix this styling issue?